# Why can't I scroll the camera wihile using FRAPS?

Tags: league-of-legends, fraps

I've decided to try to review matches to improve. I've already started using replay clients (like BaronReplay) to rewatch matches, but that gives me an omniscient perspective. To try and see gameplay from my view, I've decided to use FRAPS to record it.

However, when FRAPS is running, I can't seem to scroll the view by moving my mouse to the edge of the screen. I normally play in Windowed, but I tried changing it to Borderless and Full-screen with no results. This is a big issue since I can't really play without the ability to move the camera with my mouse.

How can I move around the camera with my mouse while using FRAPS?

Comment: Try running FRAPS in Admin mode, if you are not already. Also try running LOL in Admin mode as well.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but if you are using a geforce card, you could try using [nVidia shadowplay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay) instead of fraps. I used it a lot before I bought an ATI card and it works perfect. You can just let it record or let it save the last x minutes at a certain button press, that way you don't have to record but just press a button anytime something happens you want to look back (like teamfights). It's also great for solving discussions with friends about what exactly happened :D

Comment: @Kevin Shadowplay has the same issue (one of my friends has it).

Comment: @3ventic I never had that problem, shadowplay automatically starts recording when you start the game, no key bindings needed.

Comment: @Kevin with the manual recording. If you want the full game recorded, you won't be using shadow recording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do Is changing your recording key in fraps or your keybinding for moving the cursor out of the game in LoL.

This problem is caused by a function in LoL that allows the cursor to move out of the game which is usually used when playing with multiple monitors. By default this is the F9 Key which is used for recording in FRAPS and as already mentioned for moving the cursor out of the game.

[This thread](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1403434) tells you how to deactivate it in LoL (unfortunately I'm not too familiar with fraps but the last time I used it it was fairly easy to change the key bindings)

[This thread](https://encodingtalk.com/threads/red-border-while-recording-gameplay-cant-move-screen.3090/) is about the problem in combination with FRAPS

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I didn't know LoL had a key to unlock the cursor. Thanks!